# ILog ODM 8.0.1 : Loggging a name Rule in execution

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I want to log the name of rule, the problem :

How to get the rule name in XOM?

**OR**

Can I inject a code before execute the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But i don't know, if the rule will use this BOM. The solution is in this link: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.ref.res%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fhtml%2Filog%2Frules%2Fengine%2FIlrToolAdapter.html

Associate a ToolAdaptar and you can get a notification if a rule has been excuted. There are some functions that will be implemented. (an existing sample [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.samples/designer_smp_topics/smp_rd_ruleprogexecmon.html))

Answer (score 2):

Il you use Z/OS you will have more option in Log, associate an Observer Class, you can Logger if there are an exception in the close IF or the close Then...

Answer (score 1):

You can use BOM (add a virtual method: non existant in XOM -> ensure access to execution variables) in which you can get the name of the rule with the instance variable (an [`IlrRuleInstance`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/html/api/html/ilog/rules/engine/IlrRuleInstance.html) runtime variable containing the current executing rule): `instance.getRuleName()`

After that inject it to your XOM ensuring that you have a method accepting the ruleName: `XOMMethodLogRule(instance.getRuleName())`